# Checkbox didn't get unchecked once set it to checked in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forms

I am made a dynamic data table in React that gets all its data from a JSON file. One of the table column fields is a 'answered-status' which used to give answer status of the inquiry whether it is answered or not.

I have an 'answered' key with value either answered or unanswered in JSON. When I used that value with my checkbox. I wasn't able to switch back to the original value. Please check below sandbox link for more detail. I use the Bootstrap 4 custom checkbox.

https://p7h9x.csb.app/

Comment: There is a guideline on Stack Overflow that questions should be mostly self-contained. Could you edit this question to add a representative sample of this code to the question itself? We are conscious that the external link may break in the future, which will result in the question no longer containing any detail, and that will mean future readers cannot learn from it.

Comment: sure I will do that. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: some times code become so long that I won't able to upload it fully on StackOverflow

Comment: Yes, indeed - but showing a _representative sample_ is a good skill to have. It is OK to additionally add a sandbox link at the end. We appreciate this is more effort, given that you only want an answer, but curators here want questions to be useful in five years, even once a sandbox service has been discontinued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First there is no code for toggle checkbox

Second state missing for inquiresList

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchInquiries: null,
        answerStatus: "all",
        inquiresList : InquiresList //<--- settting into state for maintaining change
    };
}

toggleCheck = (event,inquiry_id) => {
    const inquiresList = this.state.inquiresList.map(inquiry => {
        return inquiry.id === inquiry_id ? { ...inquiry , "answered" : event.target.checked ? "answered" : "unanswered" } : inquiry
    })
    this.setState({inquiresList}); //<---- Updating state 
};

// There is no need of turnery operator for checked unchecked whole input
<input
    type="checkbox"
    ref="answerStatus"
    checked={inquiry.answered === "answered"} // <---- HERE
    onChange={(e) => this.toggleCheck(e,inquiry.id)} // <---- HERE
    className="custom-control-input"
    id={"answer-status-" + inquiry.id}
    name={"answer-status-" + inquiry.id}
/>
```

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit so-checkbox-toggle]

Further explanation on `inquiresList` function :

```
const inquiresList = this.state.inquiresList.map(inquiry => {
    return inquiry.id === inquiry_id ? // checking if inquiry id match
            // if matched we need to update that object
            { ...inquiry , "answered" : event.target.checked ? "answered" : "unanswered" } :  
            // else pass the same object as it is
            inquiry // else pass the same object as it is
})


// Why this way?
// because, we don't want to mutate state directly
{ 
    ...inquiry , // <-- extract all elements inside inquiry
    "answered" : event.target.checked ? "answered" : "unanswered" // <--- We are override the value with it
}
```

Comment: can you comment in the toggle-check function so that I able to understand the program flow.

Comment: @Pranaykumar, added, hope that will clear your doubts